# Display a table that will store for each user his first "success" date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my simple sql request:

```
select user_id, id_transaction, status_name, transaction_datetime 
from pay 
where status_name = 'success' 
  and id_transaction is not null 
order by user_id, transaction_datetime
```

And i see this

[image]

How can I display only one, first successful entry per user?

Like this

[image]

Comment: have you tried `select distinct on (user_id) user_id, id_transaction, status_name, transaction_datetime  from pay  where status_name = 'success' and id_transaction is not null  order by user_id, transaction_datetime`?

Comment: Thank you. Tried distinct user_id and got same result.
Didn't know about difference between DISTINCT and  DISTINCT ON

Comment: @JimJones wow, dang, I didn't know about `DISTINCT ON` either (despite me using Postgres since 2009, argh) but this is an amazing SQL language feature that I'm going to use a lot now... now if only everyone else (looking at you, MSSQL Server) would support it...

Comment: @Dai SQL is indeed a very powerful language... and PostgreSQL is just a dream ;)

Comment: @slavabuu so it didn't work?

Comment: @JimJones except for the tooling, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` as suggested in the comments but here is another solution using a CTE that may be more performant. I did not do anything to prove performance.

```
WITH first_success AS
(
SELECT user_id
     , status_name
     , MIN(transaction_datetime) min_ts
  FROM t
 WHERE status_name = 'success'
   AND id_transaction IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY userid, status_name
)
SELECT t2.user_id
     , t2.id_transaction
     , t2.status_name
     , t2.transaction_datetime
  FROM first_success fs
  JOIN t t2 ON  fs.min_ts = t2.transaction_datetime
            AND fs.user_id = t2.user_id
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=117022f97d30559947dcce086984a047) is a dbfiddle to show both examples in action.

Comment: Tried this to.. can confirm the performance increased a little! thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Great! You're welcome. My thought was just that `DISTINCT ON` can be a bit costly and harder for Postgres to optimize behind the scenes in comparison to `GROUP BY`.